# terrible performance with node-cassandra-cql driver, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: node.js, performance, cassandra

I'm trying to use node to insert rows to Cassandra. I previously had Mongo in Cassandra's place and I could reasonably get 1500 inserts/sec on a single node mongo. With Cassandra and node-cassandra-cql I'm getting about 175-250 inserts/sec. That's a huge drop in performance. This is on a table with no indexes.

```
cql = require("node-cassandra-cql")
... 
 if (this.dbConnection == null) {
  this.dbConnection = new cql.Client({
    hosts: this.hosts,
    keyspace: this.keyspace
  });
 }
... 
var colAndValues, statement, v;  

colAndValues = "(" + (this.fieldsWithValue.join(',')) + ") values (" + (((function() {
    var _i, _len, _results;
    _results = [];
    for (_i = 0, _len = values.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
      v = values[_i];
      _results.push('?');
    }
    return _results;
  })()).join(', ')) + ")";

  statement = "INSERT INTO " + this.table + " " + colAndValues + ";";

  this.dbConnection.execute(statement, values, cql.types.consistencies.one, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return emitter.emit('error', err + (" \nstatement: " + statement + "\nvalues: " + (JSON.stringify(values))));
    } else {
      return emitter.emit('complete', true);
    }
  });
```

OK that may be a bit cryptic, but the statements and values look like:

```
statement: 
INSERT INTO data (order_id,order_ts,transaction_id,transaction_discount,transaction_qty,transaction_total,product_category,product_profit,product_upc,product_name,product_price,product_distributor,store_id,store_name,store_state,store_region,id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);

values
[{"value":"70DQLVZLSN","hint":10},"2014-06-08T20:30:23.000Z",{"value":"1OOSC3PL9Q","hint":10},{"value":0,"hint":8},{"value":3,"hint":9},{"value":37.77,"hint":8},{"value":"Movies","hint":10},{"value":3.4,"hint":8},{"value":"PD1334R9688","hint":10},{"value":"The Hunt","hint":10},{"value":12.59,"hint":8},{"value":"IN5","hint":10},{"value":"6LMTY1OWR3","hint":10},{"value":"Sporket Spokane","hint":10},{"value":"WA","hint":10},{"value":"Northwest","hint":10},{"value":"819ddd7f-28e7-4247-90cf-03132ef8b66e","hint":12}]
```

These are just test values being inserted into a dummy database. It works fine but the performance is awful. I thought adding hints would help; it didn't. I also tried `executeAsPrepared`, no change. The docs say that connecting prior to execute is not necessary (the driver stores any existing connection that is made).

So I'm out of ideas for what I can do to speed this thing up. I would like to profile it but getting the V8 profiler running on Ubuntu has been a time sink (with no success).

Comment: I believe you are trying to insert rows separately, maybe sending individual request for each insert. I believe you should try to batch insert. I am not familiar in the technologies you are usingm therefore this is just a guess.

Comment: Few driver tips: Create 1 client instance per process lifetime; You can enable logging on the driver https://github.com/jorgebay/node-cassandra-cql#logging ; There is no need to generate the query, if the schema does not change; In order to take advantage of prepared queries, the query should be reused with different values...

Comment: @LajosArpad batch insert isn't really gonna work because in the production app the records come in at random one at a time

Comment: @jorgebg I believe the library keeps track of prepared queries and reuses them automatically. I'll look into it further.

Comment: @jcollum, can you store the commands somewhere and run a heartbeat event to batch insert the elements?

Comment: @Cmag, would you mind asking a separate question laying out what you are doing and what you are running into?  Since the library has changed quite a bit in the last two years and there could be nuances in your code that make it more apparent what the problem may be.

Comment: @AndyTolbert certainly!  Sorry about a link, but has a better explanation.  https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs-driver-user/5u3j7tSkkOY  we can also track it here :)

Comment: Okay, i have some questions: Which java version do you use? Did you checked another languages instead of nodejs? Maybe it's the driver.

Answer (score 1):

Questions from [github](https://github.com/jorgebay/node-cassandra-cql/issues/95) repository of node-cassandra-cql which can lead to an answer:

1. Are you reusing the same client instance (you should use 1)?
2. Are you warming up the pool by using client.connect method?
3. Have you enabled logging on the driver to see what is going on?
4. Is the generated query always the same (if not, you should not use prepared
   statements)?

Comment: This is coming up on 2 years old. I don't have the code. I don't think I'll be able to answer this without a bit of work. In other words, WYSIWYG, I won't/don't have any more info.

Comment: @jcollum Yup, I know. But Cmag is interested in this question so I thought this could be useful for him.

Comment: @Jehy thank you! :). I posted a potential answer, bump up driver version to 3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Folks, we've seen a similar issue.  Since version 3.0.2, things seem to be faster.  Have not had time to prove with a load test, however the change log in the driver got page references a performance chart which clearly shows 4-5x performance gain by upgrading the driver to 3.1.0